# VSTS + Visual Studio Test: Add additional logs to test output

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, azure-pipelines

We have an application and use VSTS for automated builds, tests and deployments. Everything works fine so far. I only have one problem. I'd like to add some additional logs to the test logs.

We added a simple 'Visual Studio Test' (V2) task to our build pipeline, which essentially executes all tests of all assemblies it can find (default settings). When I want to add additional logs I usually use `Console.WriteLine("bla, bla, bla")` and it shows up in the test output locally.

But the same thing doesn't work with VSTS test tasks. I only see the default output (e.g. `2017-05-30T09:10:48.5505381Z Passed   ValidatePassword_ShouldSucceed_WhenCorrectPasswordIsSet`), but not the additional `WriteLine()` calls. I already tried several other WriteLines:

```
TestContext.WriteLine($"bla, bla, bla");
Console.WriteLine($"bla, bla, bla");
Trace.WriteLine($"bla, bla, bla");
Debug.WriteLine($"bla, bla, bla");
```

None of them worked. So I guess the output of the VSTS test task is somehow decoupled from the 'normal' console/debug/trace logs.

I guess there's an easy way to add logs to the output, but I just cannot find it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

For now, vs test task only shows the output in log when the test is failed.

[image]

If the vs test step is passed, it won’t the the output message in log.

I posted an user voice [Visual Studio Test task show standard output in VSTS build log](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19452985-visual-studio-test-task-show-standard-output-in-vs), you can vote and follow up.

On the other hand, you can find the output in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\xx.trx` for temporarily use:

```
  <Results>
    <UnitTestResult executionId="0ab084d5-e9cc-46af-898e-c57cae7a8ae7" testId="fd1a9d66-d059-cd84-23d7-f655dce255f5" testName="TestMethod1" computerName="computer" duration="00:00:00.0128766" startTime="2017-05-31T15:12:51.9527754+08:00" endTime="2017-05-31T15:12:52.0627885+08:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="0ab084d5-e9cc-46af-898e-c57cae7a8ae7">
      <Output>
        <StdOut>bla, bla, bla</StdOut>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    <UnitTestResult executionId="d54ccde2-5cbe-44be-8d02-e81130b8f370" testId="fd1a9d66-d059-cd84-23d7-f655dce255f5" testName="TestMethod1" computerName="computer" duration="00:00:00.0139917" startTime="2017-05-31T15:12:52.3167945+08:00" endTime="2017-05-31T15:12:52.4268050+08:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="d54ccde2-5cbe-44be-8d02-e81130b8f370">
      <Output>
        <StdOut>bla, bla, bla</StdOut>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
```

Comment: So, the good news for me, I'm not just too stupid it really doesn't work with the default output:-) BTW, I just backed your user voice post.
Does anyone know a workaround???

Answer (score 0):

They must have added this ability since this question was asked. I simply added Console.WriteLine("some output...") to my xUnit test, and I saw the output within the VsTest task logs.